# Set cookie to redirect to beta site if clicked

Tags: php, cookies

I want an opt-in beta site, that users can also opt-out of,

On `domain.com` there will be a link to allow users to goto `beta.domain.com` I want it so that every time they visit they are automatically redirected to `beta.domain.com` but there they can also unset the cookie to just goto `domain.com`

I have tried some stuff but just ended up in a recursive loop :P

Any ideas?

Comment: What stuff have you tried? Are you using a libray? You have to give us some more information if you want us to provide more than just the logic behind it.

Comment: Cookie set in mutant-tractor.com is not available at beta.mutant-tractor.com, I think this is the problem. If you can set cookie which will be available at both, the problem will be solved

Comment: @mahadeb So XSS isn't allowed for cookies either? Would I need the beta site in a sub-dir and then use `mod_rewrite` to make it look like `beta.mutant-tractor.com`?

Comment: Yes, you can do like this. Remember - when you will set cookie, don't use beta.mutant-tractor.com. Use just the domain name like as - .mutant-tractor.com for both part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When entering `beta.domain.com` create a cookie on the domain level:

```
setcookie("BetaUser", 1, time () + (60*60*24*30), '/', '.domain.com');
```

Now when a user enters your page and you're on `domain.com` (see $_SERVER) redirect to `beta.domain.com`.

When the user wants to opt-out of your beta, provide a link to a opt-out page that unsets the cookie and redirects back to `domain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

link:

```
<a href="/?switch-to-beta.php">switch to beta</a>
```

switch-to-beta.php code:

```
setcookie('use_beta', '1', time()+3600*24*365*10, '/', 'domain.com');
header('Location: http://beta.domain.com/');
exit;
```

At start of index file on domain.com

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['use_beta']) && $_COOKIE['use_beta']){
  header('Location: http://beta.domain.com/');
  exit;
}
```

link to stop redirection on `beta.domain.com`

```
<a href="http://domain.com/switch-to-stable.php">switch to beta</a>
```

switch-to-stable.php code:

```
setcookie('use_beta', '0', time()-10000, '/', 'domain.com');
header('Location: http://domain.com/');
exit;
```

Comment: there are no XSS problems in relation to subdomains and main domains? I.e. I don't have to use `.domain.com`?

Comment: cookie is set for `domain.com`. it doesn't matter if `beta.domain.com` is `googe.com`, because the real action (redirection) is done  on `domain.com`

Comment: I'm sorry - I gave you wrong code. `switch-to-stable.php` must be on `domain.com` to be able to set the cookie even if beta subdomain is not on the same domain. Also if you use cookie on domain.com it is visible to all subdomains.